AWS EventBridge API Connection still authorizing the first time it gets hit
I have an AWS EventBridge Pipe with an API Destination as the target of it. For each execution through the pipe, the first TargetInvocation always fails due to

Unable to invoke ApiDestination endpoint: Authorization for the API destination is still in progress.

The TargetInvocationFailed log stream also mentions that it is a 400 Bad Request error
But then the retry on the pipe occurs and the second one always works fine.
Is there a way to fix this or see why its occuring?
